# Disabling JQuery Mobile button with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

this is my JQuery mobile button. This is probably an easy one. Im able to disable a html button but i cant seem to get it with this mark up.

```
<a href="" data-role="button"  class="answer_but" id="a" data-theme="b" data-answer="1">
```

This is probably an easy one. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[Disable Buttons in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875025/disable-buttons-in-jquery-mobile)

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XRjh2/16/

UPDATE:

Link button example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/gRLYQ/6/

JS

```
var clicked = false;

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    if(clicked === false) {
        $(this).addClass('ui-disabled');
        clicked = true;
        alert('Button is now disabled');
    } 
});

$('#enableButton').click(function() {
    $('#myButton').removeClass('ui-disabled');
    clicked = false; 
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="myButton">Click button</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="enableButton">Enable button</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

> Links styled like buttons have all the same visual options as true
>   form-based buttons below, but there are a few important differences.
>   Link-based buttons aren't part of the button plugin and only just use
>   the underlying buttonMarkup plugin to generate the button styles so
>   the form button methods (enable, disable, refresh) aren't supported.
>   If you need to disable a link-based button (or any element), it's
>   possible to apply the disabled class ui-disabled yourself with
>   JavaScript to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks @phil. yeah it works fine but changing my buttons to the html markup you specified breaks some functionality in my app. Do you have any suggestions as to how i can disable the given button markup?

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the class to "ui-disabled" for almost any element or button to disable it.

```
<a data-role="filter-button" data-timeframe="month" class="ui-disabled">Date</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm - Try this (assuming 'a' is the id of your jqm button):

```
// To disable
$("#a").attr("disabled","disabled");

// and enable
$("#a").attr("disabled","");
```

Comment: I tried that. Its doesnt seem to work. it works with original buttons but not jquery mobile ones.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked over this and couldn't get this to work either. Then a coworker suggested adding live to a vclick and now it works.

```
    //Disable Continue Button
        $('#icon-continue').live( 'vclick',function(event){

    var clicked = false;

             if(clicked === false) {
              $(this).addClass('ui-disabled');
              clicked = true;
              alert('Button is now disabled');   
             }
});
```