# Jquery to disable a HTML button not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get some jQuery to disable the confirm button on my form if the dropdown list is a certain value, but it doesnt seem to be working.

I have read lots of posts on here and tried various different ways.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
       // Handler for .ready() called.
       $('#MoveToCompanyId').attr("disabled", true);

       $('#DeleteAll').live("click", function () {

           if ($(this).attr("value") == "True") {
                 $('#MoveToCompanyId').attr("disabled", true);
           } else {
                 $('#MoveToCompanyId').attr("disabled", false);
                 $('#confirm').attr("disabled", true);
                 $('#MoveToCompanyId').change(function () {
                     if ($("#MoveToCompanyId option:selected").text() != "---Select Company---") {
                    $('#confirm').removeAttr("disabled");
                    alert($("#MoveToCompanyId option:selected").text());
                }
                else {
                    $('#confirm').attr("disabled", true);
                    alert("I should be disabled!");
                }

            });
        }
        });
     });

    </script>
```

Can anyone see any problems with it?

Just to clarify, i know it gets into the correct code blocks as my alerts are working. Its just the button disabling that is not working.

Kind Regards,

Gareth

Comment: Try `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work either. I am looking at the button in Firebug and it never seems to add the disabled attribute at all.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili not easily as its calling loads of clever functions from MVC framework.

Comment: @GazWinter have you checked for other attribute ? (e.g: .attr("someproperty","somevalue")).

Comment: @GazWinter can you post a section of the html that goes with the function?

Comment: Thanks but i got it working now using the method @FelixKling suggested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using

```
prop('disabled',true)
prop('disabled',false)
```

if you are using jQuery 1.6+ then you should be using prop.

Read more about [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The `.prop()` method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the `.attr()` method. The `.val()` method should be used for getting and setting value.

Comment: thanks for that advice wirey, sadly this doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: @janex Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Disregard my comment, it put the disabled prop in the button just fine, but my button is still clickable. I didn't think I had to check if the disabled prop was on or not on the button before letting the code continue. I thought disabled actually disabled all events for that button. My bad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @janex are you using jQuery UI buttons?  If so that's a different story,  but with regular buttons it should prevent clicks if they are disabled

Comment: no i'm using regular buttons but with custom css, but i'm listening to the touchstart event not click event, since its for a phonegap app @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, i see the disabled added to the button but touch events are still happening.

Comment: @janex not sure if you are using jQM also.. if you are this will probably help out http://stackoverflow.com/a/5875143/1385672 .  If it doesn't, if you could create a fiddle I could help you try and figure it out

Answer (score 3):

You should be using

```
.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

to disable a control and

```
.removeAttr('disabled')
```

to enable it.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: Thanks Dave, this is one of the things i already tried to no avail!

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili specifying an arbitrary value for 'disabled' will disable a control but the only way to re-enable it is to remove the 'disabled' attribute altogether

Comment: what is your problem with removing it then?

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys, i got it working using the .prop way.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili no problem at all; the point is that if you leave the 'disabled' attribute on a control it should always be disabled (though some browsers maybe behave differently) as 'disabled', like 'checked', 'selected' and 'nowrap' are boolean attributes; their value doesn't matter except for XML conformance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```

instead of

```
attr("disabled", true);
```