# How to make button disabled for touchstart / touchend event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was surprised to see that the disabled attribute for the button is ignored on the mobile version of the site. How to disable the button for touchstart / touchend events? `<button ontouchend="alert();" disabled="disabled" style="touch-event: none">Test for touch</button>`show `alert()` after touch and ignoring disabled attribute. I tried to apply `touch-event: none`in style - nothing happened

UPD. Here is some code - its workable but it not fine for simple use

```
$("button").on("touchend", function()
{
    if($(this).is(":disabled") == false)
    alert(1)    
});
```

Comment: Please have a look at this answer, might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5875143/2402610)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue and located this topic.

As long as I tried it, `disabled` property disabled `onClick`, yet doesn't disabled `onTouchStart` and `onTouchEnd`.

And actually, `onTouchStart` and `onTouchEnd` is not an official property for `<button>`. I guess that's why.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative u could use css adding the `touch-action: none` property to the button container